# How to choose a specific video stream from an MKV file with multiple video streams, using HTML5 video tag?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mkv

I have a .mkv file with 2 video streams in it.

While playing in browser with HTML5 video tag, how do I select a specific stream ?

I have tried

video src="1234.mkv#Strem 0"

but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:
[HTML 5 Video Player with multiple video streams](http://visuallounge.techsmith.com/2011/10/dev_corner_-_html_5_video_play.html)

Comment: He demonstration is about playing multiple video streams at once from 2 different video files. But in my case playing multiple streams at once from a single video .mkv file.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 video tag, as yet, does not support playing multiple streams within a single file.

Having said that, there seems to be some work going on to support such a feature.

More information at following links 
(x) http://blog.gingertech.net/2011/05/01/html5-multi-track-audio-or-video/ 
(x) http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#media-resources-with-multiple-media-tracks